# app .NET somente consegue acessar Web service com Fiddler ligado

Tags: .net, web-service

Tenho um aplicativo cliente desenvolvido em .NET, não estou conseguindo chamar um WS através da URL que foi passado pelo meu provedor.
Fiz o teste usando o SOAP UI e funcionou perfeitamente, recebi a resposta sem problemas, mas o meu Aplicativo só funciona quando estou monitorando a conexão utilizando o FIDDLER.
Já verifiquei o seguinte ponto:

1. Configurei o Fiddler para não funcionar como PROXY. O meu serviço .NET continua funcionando;

Já pesquisei que o Fiddler faz uma cópia das configurações de PROXY da minha máquina, mas não consigo entender porque com o Fiddler funciona e sem ele não funciona mais. 
Observação: ano passado este app já existia e funcionava perfeitamente, tivemos que pará-lo por um ano e agora ao tentar retomar estou tendo este problema.

A mensagem de erro que recebo é: *The request failed with HTTP status 502: Proxy Error ( Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL). ).*

PS: Não coloquei o fonte da chamada porque eu não o tenho agora, fica com uma outra equipe mas posso conseguir se acharem de extrema importância.

Answer (score 1):

Este meu problema era que a aplicação .NET era executada por um usuário que não tinha privilégios suficientes para completar a requisição ao web service.
Quando eu utilizava o FIDDLER era com o meu usuário, que tinha as permissões.
Ao trocar o usuário que executa o aplicativo por um usuário com permissões o problema foi resolvido.

Uma boa prática que irei adotar, é executar o FIDDLER com o mesmo usuário que executa a aplicação problemática.